# How does this proof that the square of an integer, not divisible by 5, leaves a remainder of 1 or 4 when divided by 5 work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Below I have a part of a proof of the fact that the square of an integer, not divisible by $5$, leaves a remainder of $1$ or $4$ when divided by $5$. But I am wondering where does the part highlighted in blue come from?

[image: Image showing if n=5k+1 then n^2 = 25 k^2 + 10k + 1 with the 10k highlighted, and so on]

Comment: There's no modular arithmetic in this (so why the tag?).  It would have been easier (slightly) using modular arithmetic:  $2^2 = 4 \equiv 4 \operatorname{mod} 5$ and $3^2 \equiv (-2)^2 \equiv 4 \operatorname{mod} 5$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

1) $(5k+1)^2=(5k)^2+2*5k+1^2=25k^2+10k+1$

Comment: This is a complete answer and there is nothing wrong with that; why not write it like one.

Answer (score 1):

**Super-Big Hint**: $$\begin{align}(5k+a)^2&=(5k+a)(5k+a)\\&=5k\cdot(5k+a)+a\cdot(5k+a)\\&=(5k)^2+5k\cdot a+a\cdot 5k+a\cdot a\\&=(5k)^2+2a\cdot 5k+a^2\end{align}$$

Comment: This is a complete answer and there is nothing wrong with that; why not write it like one.

Comment: @quid: Because it *isn't* actually complete. It still requires a modicum of understanding on the OP's part (the encouragement of which is my wont) to fill in the (admittedly "small") gap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; personally I find this "wordless" style of answering quite strange. It seems quite common around here though.

Comment: Math should be represented by math, not words.